# How to change "client-output-buffer-limit" in google cloud memorystore - Redis

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

I need to modify Following values in GCP memorystore-redis .

```
client-output-buffer-limit slave
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I do not see anything in the public documentation that would document if is possible or not but I think is worth trying if you didn't from the redis.conf file to see in a test project.